# Disable ImageView Anti-Aliasing in JavaFX

Tags: java, image-processing, javafx, antialiasing

I made an `ImageView` in JavaFX and load a pixel art into it. And I scaled up, but I can't clearly see the pixels of the art. The problem should be the anti-aliasing. So I need to see clearly the pixels like on the second link. How can I turn anti-aliasing off?

I tried with `img1.setSmooth(false);`

**What I made in JavaFX:** [image: image1]

**How it supposed to look like:** [image: image2] *//preview made in piskel*

Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    StackPane hb = new StackPane();
    Image image = new Image("pixelart.png");
    ImageView img = new ImageView(image);
    img.setFitWidth(500);
    img.setFitHeight(500);
    img.setSmooth(false);
    hb.getChildren().add(img);
    root.getChildren().addAll(hb);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

pixelart.png:
[image: image3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to turn smoothing off when you construct the [`Image`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html). Set the last argument of the [constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,double,double,boolean,boolean)), `smooth`, to `false`.

```
Image image = new Image("pixelart.png", 400, 400, true, false);
```

[image]

As tested:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Image image = new Image("pixelart.png", 400, 400, true, false);
        ImageView view = new ImageView(image);
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```